# Match not working in MongoDB. Match is returning an empty array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to create an aggregation pipeline. The beginning of the code works okay. But when comes to the $match, the code returns nothing. Here is my code:

```
    var userId = req.params.UserId
    const measure = await Measure.aggregate([
        {
            $project: {
                user: 1, creationDate: 1, WaterConsumption: 1
            }
        }, 
        {
            $match: {
                user: userId
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    $dayOfMonth: "$creationDate"
                },
                waterConsumption: {$sum :  "$WaterConsumption"}
            }
        }
    ]);
    return res.json({measure})
```

My data is:

```
{
  "measures": [
    {
      "creationDate": "2021-03-19T10:25:05.674Z",
      "_id": "605870bffa87a605bf2a983a",
      "avgPower": 8241,
      "WaterConsumption": 22,
      "avgTemperature": 45,
      "shower": "5fb56ce7734b7e04b9c97c9b",
      "user": "5f6cb0496a8c5a0deaa1a746"
    },
    {
      "creationDate": "2021-03-19T10:25:05.674Z",
      "_id": "605870d9fa87a605bf2a983b",
      "avgPower": 8241,
      "WaterConsumption": 22,
      "avgTemperature": 45,
      "shower": "5fb56ce7734b7e04b9c97c9b",
      "user": "5f6cb0496a8c5a0deaa1a746"
    },
    {
      "creationDate": "2021-03-17T10:25:05.674Z",
      "_id": "605870ebfa87a605bf2a983c",
      "avgPower": 4300,
      "WaterConsumption": 32,
      "avgTemperature": 28,
      "shower": "5fb56d04734b7e04b9c97c9c",
      "user": "5f6cb0496a8c5a0deaa1a746",
    }...
  ]
```

The code runs perfect till it reaches the $match. If I console my userId it is a string with the user value "5f6cb0496a8c5a0deaa1a746". I don't know why $match is not working. The $group is working perfectly.
I tried to swap the match to $match:{user: req.params.UserId} but the code keeps returning an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to match string with ObjectID that's why your `$match` is not working.

[ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

Working demo with ObjectID - https://mongoplayground.net/p/Oz95gFwvp9X

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const ObjectID = mongodb.ObjectID;
const userId = ObjectID(req.params.UserId); // convert your userid to ObjctedID format
```

Eg - userId - `5f6cb0496a8c5a0deaa1a746` will be converted to `ObjectId("5f6cb0496a8c5a0deaa1a746")`

Not working with string - https://mongoplayground.net/p/5PN8WeXt2zc

Comment: This is it my fellow mate! Worked like a charm, thanks for your help.